# Why are my React NavBar buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

I am creating a clone of the Netflix web app. I am currently developing the landing page. I have included my code below. This is one of the few different ways I have attempted structuring this page.

The layout currently is appearing how I want it to look, however the "main-slice__language-button" and the "main-slice__signin-button" at the top of the page are not working – meaning nothing happens when I click the select dropdown, and the Sign In button is not appearing as clickable. Can anyone explain why it does not work this way and any suggestions for better alternatives?

[screenshot of landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNfDU.jpg)

````
import backgroundImage from '../../images/mooshflix-background.jpeg';
import netflixLogo from '../../images/netflix-logo.png';

import './MainSlice.css';


const MainSlice = () => {

    return (
        <div className='main-slice-container'>
            <img className='background-image' src={backgroundImage} alt='mooshflix background' />
            <div className='header'>
                <img className='main-slice__logo' src={netflixLogo} alt='' />
                <div className='main-slice__header-buttons'>
                    <select className='main-slice__language-button'>
                        <option>English</option>
                        <option>Spanish</option>
                    </select>
                    <button className='main-slice__signin-button'>Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='main-slice__text-container'>
                    <h1 className='main-slice__title'>Unlimited movies, TV shows, and more.</h1>
                    <h2 className='main-slice__subtitle'>Watch anywhere. Cancel anytime.</h2>
                    <div className='main-slice__email-form-container'>
                        <h3 className='email-form-title'>Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</h3>
                        <form>
                            <input placeholder='Email Address' ></input>
                            <button className='main-slice__email-form-button'>Get Started ></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainSlice;```
````

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Did you get a error message? Or did nothing simply happen?

Comment: Also if you are using event listeners or whatever in your post you said the classes were `main_slice__language_button` and `main_slice__signin_button`, but in your code they appear to be `main-slice__language-button` and `main-slice__signin-button`. Notice the clashing dashes and underscores.

Comment: I edited the main post to describe how it is not working. The select button does not provide the dropdown selector when clicked, and the Sign In button is not clickable at all, although it is a button. I have fixed the typos in the post, thank you for pointing out the clashing dashes/underscores. This was only a typo in the post, not my code editor.

Comment: Well, the button probably doesn't do anything because you didn't make it do anything... Try adding something like `<button className="..." onClick={() => alert("Clicked!")}>...</button>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

because you DID NOT do anything, what event did u call for that button? you have to add some event listeners like onClick to your btn, like below:

```
const onStart = () => {
  DO STH WHAT YOU WANT
}

<button className='main-slice__email-form-button' onClick={onStart}>
    Get Started
</button>
```